# trace and involution permutations: Part I

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $\operatorname{Inv}(\mathfrak{S}_n):=\{\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n: \pi^2=1\}$ be the set of [*involutions*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationInvolution.html) in the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$. Denote $I_n:=\#\operatorname{Inv}(\mathfrak{S}_n)$. Let $\operatorname{tr}(\pi)$ be the number of fixed points of a permutation $\pi$. We know
$$I_n=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{n!}{2^kk!(n-2k)!}.$$
Some experimental evidence convinces me that it is possible to express $I_{n+m}$ in terms of a sum of polynomials in $\operatorname{tr}(\pi)$ over $\operatorname{Inv}(\mathfrak{S}_n)$. We may attempt a modest special case.

> **Question.** Is this true?
>   $$I_{n+2}=\sum_{\pi\in \operatorname{Inv}(\mathfrak{S}_n)}\left(\operatorname{tr}(\pi)^2+\operatorname{tr}(\pi)+2\right).$$

**Note.** $\operatorname{tr}(\pi)^2$ is understood as $\operatorname{tr}(\pi)\operatorname{tr}(\pi)$.

Comment: I'm not sure whether my edit changed what you intended. You wrote either $$I_{n+2} = \sum(\cdots\cdots)^2.$$ or $$ I_{n+2} = \sum(\cdots\cdots)^.$$ where the latter has a superscript period. Did you have a $2$ there, or just a superscript period?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let us identify an involution $\sigma$ in $\mathfrak{S}_n$ with a set partition $\Pi_\sigma$ of $[n] := \{1,2,...,n\}$ into nonempty blocks of size at most two in the obvious way: we have $\{a,b\} \in \Pi_\sigma$ if and only if $\sigma(a)=b$. This is obviously a bijection between involutions and such set partitions; and the fixed points of $\sigma$ correspond exactly to the singletons of $\Pi_\sigma$.

Now to get a set partition $\Pi'$ of $[n+2]$ with block sizes at most two from such a set partition $\Pi_\sigma$ of $[n]$ corresponding to the involution $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n$, we just have to decide what blocks the elements $n+1$ and $n+2$ belong to:

- they could each be singletons (one way);
- they could be in a size-two block together (one way);
- $n+1$ could form a block of size two with something that was a singleton in $\Pi_\sigma$, while $n+2$ is a singleton ($\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)$ many ways);
- $n+2$ could form a block of size two with something that was a singleton in $\Pi_\sigma$, while $n+1$ is a singleton ($\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)$ many ways);
- $n+1$ could form a block of size two with something that was a singleton in $\Pi_\sigma$, and $n+2$ could form a block of size two with a different singleton in $\Pi_\sigma$ ($\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)(\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)-1)$ many ways).

Adding these all together, we get $1+1+\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)+\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)+\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)(\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)-1)=\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)^2+\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)+2$ such set partitions for each involution $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n$, proving your claimed identity.

EDIT:

Here is the formula for the more general case of $I_{n+m}$:

$$ I_{n+m} = \sum_{\sigma \in \mathrm{Inv}(\mathfrak{S}_n)} \sum_{j=0}^{m} \binom{m}{j} \cdot I_{m-j} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)!}{(\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)-j)!}.$$

It can be proved in the same manner: for each involution $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n$, we choose $j$ of the elements of $\{n+1,n+2,\ldots,n+m\}$ to join with singletons in $\Pi_{\sigma}$, and hence choose an ordered subset of $j$ singletons from $\Pi_{\sigma}$ to pair with these elements, and then we put an involution on the remaining $m-j$ elements of $\{n+1,n+2,\ldots,n+m\}$ in $I_{m-j}$ ways (with the convention $I_0 =1$).

EDIT 2:

Maybe one final repackaging of this result is worth recording.

Set $I_n(t) := \sum_{\sigma \in \mathrm{Inv}(\mathfrak{S}_n)} t^{\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)}$ for all $n \geq 0$ (with $I_0(t)=1$). Then for all $m \geq 0$,
$$ I_{n+m}(t) = \left(\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k} \, I_{m-k}(t) \, \frac{d^k}{dt^k} \right) \, I_{n}(t).$$
In particular,
$$ I_{n+1}(t) = \left(t+\frac{d}{dt}\right) I_{n}(t);$$
hence we also have,
$$ I_{n+m}(t) = \left(t+\frac{d}{dt}\right)^m I_{n}(t).$$

Comment: This basic bijection between perfect matchings of $[2n]$ and fixed point-free involutions in $\mathfrak{S}_{2n}$ should allow you to prove all the identities about $I_{n+m}$ you were considering.

Comment: Define $f_m(x) := \sum_{j=0}^{m} \binom{m}{j} I_{m-j} \frac{x!}{(x-j)!}$. Then $f_0 = 1$,  $f_1 = x+1$, $f_2 = x^2+x+2$, $f_3 = x^3+5x+4$, $f_4=x^4-2x^3+11x^2+6x+10$, etc. The presence of this negative sign in $f_4$ means you are unlikely to get a nice combinatorial formula for the coefficients of $f_m$, unfortunately.

Comment: On the contrary, you don't always have to use $x^j$ as a basis. The family $\frac{x!}{(x-j)!}$ work equally well and the coefficients $\binom{m}jI_{m-j}$, as you showed, are perfectly combinatorial.

Comment: As my last edit should make clear, this stuff is closely related to Stanley's theory of differential posets: http://dedekind.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/77.pdf